# Extending the width of a picturebox from the left side

Tags: c#, width, picturebox

So I want to increase the width of a picturebox from the left side of the picturebox and have been unable to find a way to do this...

```
imgBeam1.Left += xChange;
imgBeam1.Width -= xChange; //I want this to move the width from the left side.
```

My plan is to move the picturebox to the right, while extending the width to the left.

Can anyone help?

Maybe there is a more creative way of doing this?

EDIT: 
This was for a DBZ beam race / beam struggle game I was working on in my spare time, and in the beam struggle part of the game, the character of the right side of the form has a much nicer way of displaying the beam as I can move the width of the picturebox to the right, while moving the picturebox left. While with the character on the left side of the form, I can only extend the width to the right which just shows sections of the image at a time.

Because of how images are loaded in to a picturebox (from left to right with the leftside showing first) I'm not sure if I could get the same effect. And I cannot find a way to extend the left side of the pictureboxes width anyways.

But thankyou for your replys. I made this account today, and didn't think this would be too hard to explain, but it was. Maybe next time I will show images instead, as it's much easier to explain that way. Thanks!

EDIT 2:
-visual explanation

[image]

Comment: Close but the signs both(!)  are wrong.

Comment: Putting a (-) sign for Left would move the image to the left, which is not what I want. 
I want the picturebox to move right, while extending the width of the left side of the picturebox to the left.

I'm not sure this is possible because of how the image is loaded in to a picturebox... So it probably is a waste of time asking. 

I will just stick with extending the width to the right.

Comment: _extending the width of the left side of the picturebox to the left._ ??? The left side has no width, it only has a position. - Well, it looks as if your are not really asking about the picturebox but about the image displayed in it? Unfortunately this makes the question even more unclear!

Comment: Well, outside of coding, the picturebox has 8 points which I can click and drag on to extend the size of the picturebox. I can drag the left side of the picturebox to the left which will extend it's width. I cannot find a way of doing this by code. I can only extend the width to the right or inward to the left side -.- really sorry for my bad explanations!

Comment: _I can drag the left side of the picturebox to the left which will extend it's width._ Well, but this __also__ moves it to the left by the same amount, which is not what you want?

Comment: You're right, but then id move the picturebox to the right, which would cancel that out.

Comment: OK, and how is the result different from simly making the width bigger?? You really ought to make a sketch!

Comment: I have added sketch with explanations

Comment: Ah, I had suspected as much. Designer or code: There are only the (2) SizeMode options: either Normal or Centered. For more flexibility you need to put/nest the PictureBox into a Panel and move it around in it. Turn off its Border and set the backcolor the same as the Panel's! Maybe set the Pbox to Autosize..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand your post is not really about changing the **outer size** of the `PictureBox` but about moving the `Image` **inside** it.

But this is not possible. All you can do is choose between the two `SizeModes`:

- `Normal` will put the image to the top left.
- `Center` will, yes, center it in the control.

So to make it look like it is moving or placed differently, e.g. aligned to the right you can use this workaround:

- Add the `PictureBox` to a `Panel`.
- Make the Panel as small as you had your PictureBox to make it act as a 'viewport'.
- Make the Image larger, maybe even full sized, i.e. `SizeMode Autosize`.
- Remove the `Border` from the `PictureBox` and add it to the `Panel` instead.
- Keep the `PictureBox` `Backcolor Transparent`.

[image]

Now you can move the `PictureBox` inside the `Panel` and it will look as if only the `Image` is moving under the viewport..:

[image]

Here is the code to move it left and back right with the mouse :

```
Point mDown = Point.Empty;
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mDown = e.Location;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left))
        pictureBox1.Left += e.X - mDown.X;
}
```

Note that the large `PictureBox` is **nested** inside the small `Panel`, not the other way around!

Of course  animations or other layout changes are also possible..

Comment: Thanks a lot man! This is definitely something along the lines of what I was looking for :) You're a G. Very good explanation/formatting!